# LabVIEW 2018 USB Webcam Image Grab

Tags: webcam, labview, webcam-capture

I'm looking to capture an image from my usb webcam in LabVIEW 2018.  I've looked at older posts (the one from Lava working with the 'free' portions of V&M Toolkit, another webcam test that hangs my computer when trying to run and a few others).  What is the best way to do this in the newer LabVIEWs?  All the examples I've seen (none of which run correctly or well) are all from 2011-ish timeframe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the task (like, for what you are going to use camera), but you could use [NI Vision Acquisition Software](https://www.ni.com/cs-cz/support/downloads/drivers/download.vision-acquisition-software.html#356586) - which provides set of functions to access the camera, acquire images and videos and process them (basically, IMAQ drivers is what you need). Or, if you are going to use your camera for some kind of test application (vision inspection) - then you'd better check [Vision Builder for Automated Inspection](https://www.ni.com/cs-cz/shop/software/products/vision-builder-for-automated-inspection.html).
Those are the easiest (but not the cheapest) ways to acquire images from the various cameras using LabVIEW.

**UPDATE**:
License scheme for the software could be found here - [Licensing National Instruments Vision Software](https://www.ni.com/cs-cz/support/documentation/supplemental/18/licensing-national-instruments-vision-software.html). Description of each software component is also here - [Does My Camera Use NI-IMAQ, NI-IMAQdx or NI-IMAQ I/O?](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019MEqSAM&l=cs-SK). So in order to use 3rd party USB camera, one need to have NI-IMAQdx, which requires license.

Comment: Hey @kosist thanks for the reply!  All I'm trying to do is show what the webcam sees on a front panel and save an image.  Is the VAS free or does it cost money just to do this task?

Comment: @gergalern, I'm afraid that it is payed, I've updated the answer.